# SharePoint 2013 Search: Searching files "Modified by Me"

Tags: 2013, search

I have a search view that shows all files modified in the last 15 days.

What I want is a personalized view of this, I can partially achieve this by adding "ModifiedBy:{User.Name}" in the search query as explained here: http://www.sherweb.com/blog/displaying-relevant-information-sharepoint-search-results-web-part/

Unfortunately, for some reason the results I get are wrong. Many results are not included. When I remove the above parameter, these do surface (And I can see on the file's metadata that I was the one who editted these documents).

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try an incremental crawl and check.

Comment: Hi Amal, everything's properly indexed because the results do surface, just not with this parameter. Also, this is SharePoint Online, no crawling options available except for the typical "reindex this list"

Comment: I think that you got not all sources, bemause You did not have mapped  the "modified by" crawled property, that you search, properly mapped  to a Managed property. Can you Check this?